# Using tikz-calc addition of coordinates along with macros

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, coordinates, tikz-calc

I am trying to use `tikz-calc` to automatically calculate coordinates in custom macros, using the coordinate addition function `($ (x,y) + (a,b) $)`. Things seem to go awry when I try to add coordinates which are themselves the output of a macro. e.g. I can't understand why in this MWE, the first three coordinates plot fine, but the other two (commented) don't.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\trig(#1)(#2){ ( {(#2)*cos(#1)}, {(#2)*sin(#1)} ) }

    \node at (0,3) {hi};
    \node at \trig(70)(2) {hi};
    \node at ($ (0,3) + (3,0) $) {hi};
%   \node at ($ (0,3) + \trig(70)(2) $) {hi};
%   \node at ($ (0,3) + {\trig(70)(2)} $) {hi};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer** this is internal expansion magic, so this is my interpretation.

I think that when scanning the expression `calc` is explicitly looking for `(` and `)`, so

1. using `()` as delimiters for the macro arguments is not a good idea, and
2. you have to provide the `(` at the first level, without any need to expand macros.

The first occurrence works (I think) because is at the top level... but better not to live dangerously. It is marked as "point 1" in the code.

So I defined a macro using normal arguments (`\mtrig`) that provides the coordinates without the surrounding parenthesis.

Anyway, I imagine this is used just as an example, because polar coordinates are available in Ti*k*Z (last red example).

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\trig#1#2{({#2*cos(#1)}, {#2*sin(#1)})}
    \def\mtrig#1#2{{#2*cos(#1)}, {#2*sin(#1)}}

    \node at (0,3) {hi};
    \node at \trig{70}{2} {hi}; %note 1
    \node[red] at (\mtrig{70}{2}) {ha}; % better
    \node at ($ (0,3) + (3,0) $) {hi};
    \node at ($ (0,3) + (\mtrig{70}{2}) $) {hi};
    \node at ($ (0,3) + (\mtrig{70}{2}) $) {hi};
    \node[red] at ($ (0,3) + (70:2) $) {ha};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about polar coordinates